# Can't use Keras CSVLogger callbacks in Sagemaker script mode. It fails to write the log file on S3 ( error - No such file or directory )

Tags: tensorflow, keras, amazon-sagemaker

I have this script where I want to get the callbacks to a separate CSV file in sagemaker custom script docker container. But when I try to run in local mode, it fails giving the following error. I have a hyper-parameter tuning job(HPO) to run and this keeps giving me errors. I need to get this local mode run correctly before doing the HPO.

[image]

In the notebook I use the following code.

```
from sagemaker.tensorflow import TensorFlow

tf_estimator = TensorFlow(entry_point='lstm_model.py', 
                          role=role,
                          code_location=custom_code_upload_location,
                          output_path=model_artifact_location+'/',
                          train_instance_count=1, 
                          train_instance_type='local',
                          framework_version='1.12', 
                          py_version='py3',
                          script_mode=True,
                          hyperparameters={'epochs': 1},
                          base_job_name='hpo-lstm-local-test'
                         )

tf_estimator.fit({'training': training_input_path, 'validation': validation_input_path})
```

In my **lstm_model.py** script the following code is used.

```
lgdir = os.path.join(model_dir, 'callbacks_log.csv')
csv_logger = CSVLogger(lgdir, append=True)

regressor.fit(x_train, y_train, batch_size=batch_size,
              validation_data=(x_val, y_val), 
              epochs=epochs,
              verbose=2,
              callbacks=[csv_logger]
              )
```

I tried creating a file before hand like shown below using tensorflow backend. But it doesn't create a file. ( K : tensorflow Backend, tf: tensorflow )

```
filename = tf.Variable(lgdir , tf.string)
content = tf.Variable("", tf.string)
sess = K.get_session()
tf.io.write_file(filename, content)
```

I can't use any other packages like pandas to create the file as the TensorFlow docker container in SageMaker for custom scripts doesn't provide them. They give only a limited amount of packages.

Is there a way I can write the csv file to the S3 bucket location, before the fit method try to write the callback. Or is that the solution to the problem? I am not sure.

If you can even suggest other suggestions to get callbacks, I would even accept that answer. But it should be worth the effort.

This docker image is really narrowing the scope.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well for starters, you can always make your own docker image using the Tensorflow image as a base. I work in Tensorflow 2.0 so this will be slightly different for you but here is an example of my image pattern:

```
# Downloads the TensorFlow library used to run the Python script
FROM tensorflow/tensorflow:2.0.0a0 # you would use the equivalent for your TF version

# Contains the common functionality necessary to create a container compatible with Amazon SageMaker
RUN pip install sagemaker-containers -q 

# Wandb allows us to customize and centralize logging while maintaining open-source agility
RUN pip install wandb -q # here you would install pandas

# Copies the training code inside the container to the design pattern created by the Tensorflow estimator
# here you could copy over a callbacks csv
COPY mnist-2.py /opt/ml/code/mnist-2.py 
COPY callbacks.py /opt/ml/code/callbacks.py 
COPY wandb_setup.sh /opt/ml/code/wandb_setup.sh

# Set the login script as the entry point
ENV SAGEMAKER_PROGRAM wandb_setup.sh # here you would instead launch lstm_model.py
```

I believe you are looking for a pattern similar to this, but I prefer to log all of my model data using [Weights and Biases](https://www.wandb.com/). They're a little out of data on their SageMaker integration but I'm actually in the midst of writing an updated tutorial for them. It should certainly be finished this month and include logging and comparing runs from hyperparameter tuning jobs

Comment: Here's an additional necessary resource you may have already seen: https://github.com/awslabs/amazon-sagemaker-examples/blob/master/advanced_functionality/tensorflow_bring_your_own/tensorflow_bring_your_own.ipynb

Comment: The `sagemaker-containers` package has been deprecated. You should instead install `sagemaker-training` for training containers and `sagemaker-inference` for inference containers.